# How to upload a patch file for nvda by bazaar

Tags: python, bazaar, nvda

I found these errors, when I try to commit a file to nvda main through bazaar.

```
bzr: ERROR: Cannot lock LockDir(chroot-2373194732:///nvda/main/.bzr/branch/lock): Transport operation not possible: readonly transport 

bzr: ERROR: No tracker specified for bug #1353. Use the form 'tracker:id' or specify a default bug tracker using the `bugtracker` option.
```

Answer (score 0):

Please post your full command.

So far it looks like you don't have permission to commit to main.

To fix the 2nd problem, use `--fixes lp:1353`.

In any case please update your question to include the complete command you used and then I will update this answer.